# Background color height after dynamic content added

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The body background color of my page is set to take up 100% height and to not repeat. However, after I dynamically add elements to the page with jQuery, the height of the document changes, and the background color no longer takes up 100%.

Here's my CSS:

```css
 html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
        background: linear-gradient(#51B5D5, #38DAD4);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        padding: 0 1rem;
        /*padding-top: 10vh;*/
        font-weight: 300;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide an image/example of how it looks after new content is added?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define the height of the body. Take that out and it should automatically cover the whole page with the background color.

Comment: also you don't need to define no repeat for a color

Comment: *Defining a height go against responsive design principles in web

Comment: If I don't define a height 100%, the background color/gradient does not take up the whole page, especially when there isn't a lot of content on the page before the dynamic elements are added.

Comment: Put the background on a container div, with all of your page contents inside that div. Don't specify a height for it and it should automatically cover the entire height of the page with your gradient

Comment: Try playing around with different options. Simply putting it on a body with no height is working on my page but there might be something conflicting in your CSS that is making it act unexpectedly. For a background, you can use a wrapper div, define it on the body or html tags, you can also define a background or a background image for linear gradients.. Try them all until you find one that works for you.